# How to merge and reshape nested objects using JQ?

Tags: json, jq

Hy,

I've got data like this:

```json
[
  {
    "bindings": [
      {
        "members": [
          "userA",
          "userB"
        ],
        "role": "admin"
      },
      {
        "members": [
          "userA"
        ],
        "role": "user"
      }
    ],
    "projects": "p1"
  },
  { [...]
  },
]
```

I would like to transform it to this:

```json
{
  "userA": {
    "p1": [
      "admin",
      "user",
    ],
    "p2": [
      "viewer"
    ]
  },
  "userB": {
    [...]
  }
}
```

I suppose I'm close with this solution:

```json
.[] | .projects as $project | .bindings[] | .role as $role | .members[] as $user | { ($user):  {($project): [(.role)]} }
```

My problem is the reduce, I'm doing this:

```json
[ <previous expression> ] | reduce .[] as $x ({}; . * $x )
```

And it give me this:

```json
{
  "userA": {
    "p1": [
      "user"
    ],
    "p2": [
      "viewer"
    ]
  },
  [...]
}
```

As you can see, the list of roles, is not "merged".

How can I merge list within object ?

For "real" data sample, please see here: https://jqplay.org/s/-MOej2i6Zh

Comment: Your sample input is neither valid JSON nor very informative.  Please follow the [mcve] guidelines. Thanks.

Comment: @peak I've add a snippet because stackoverflow say there is too much code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your jqplay example, the following jq program produces the output shown below:

```
reduce .[] as $o ({};
  $o.projects as $projects
  | reduce $o.bindings[] as $b (.;
      $b.role as $role
      | reduce $b.members[] as $member (.;
          .[$member][$projects] += [$role])) )
```

#### Output

```
{
  "userA": {
    "p1": [
      "admin",
      "user"
    ],
    "p2": [
      "viewer"
    ]
  },
  "userB": {
    "p1": [
      "admin"
    ],
    "p2": [
      "viewer",
      "user"
    ]
  }
}
```

#### More succinctly ...

```
reduce .[] as $o ({};
  reduce $o.bindings[] as $b (.;
    reduce $b.members[] as $member (.;
      .[$member][$o.projects] += [$b.role])) )
```

Comment: @djabx - It's much the same as a nested loop -- `for ($o in .[]) { for ($b in $o.bindings) { for ($member in $b.members[]) { ... } }`

Answer (score 2):

With an up-to-date version of JQ, you can emulate a nested loop using [`reduce`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Reduce) as below to achieve this.

```
reduce .[] as { $bindings, $projects } ({};
  reduce $bindings[] as { $members, $role } (.;
    reduce $members[] as $member (.;
      .[$member][$projects] += [ $role ]
    )
  )
)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/KUTlF_UaEm)</sup>